# Linux с встроенным Python 2.7.3 (х32)

Tags: python, linux

Привет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какая ОС семейства линукс имеет Python 2.7.3 (х32) (ну т.е последнюю стабильную в ветке 2.х) сразу после установки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.10

```
# python -VPython 2.7.3
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это на серверной? Она предустановлена или вы после установки проапгрейдили ?

Comment: Установлены все обновления, а там нет интернета?

Comment: где нет интернета?

Comment: на той машине, на которой планируете установить линукс с питоном

Comment: интернет есть, а что я как-то могу проверить версию питона у различных ОС линукса не установив их?

Comment: скорее всего можно в списках пакетов к релизу каждой из них.. но мы не об этом. Ubuntu 12.10 десктопная уже отвечает требованиям, зачем искать дальше?

Comment: мне серверная нужна поэтому :) это для сервера

Comment: на серверной 12.04 x86 тоже Python 2.7.3, только что проверил )) думаю, что на более новой не будет меньше